How to prove that $$ is in $\mathsf{NP} \setminus \mathsf{P}?$
Suppose that there exists a function $:\{0,1\}^ → \{0,1\}^$
such that,  is computable in polynomial time; and the following task cannot be computed in polynomial time (that is, there are $ ∈ \{0,1\}^$, for which, it cannot be computed efficiently):
Given $ = ()$, find any $\hat{}∈ \{0,1\}^$ such that $(\hat{}) = .$
Define the language,
$$ = \{(, ) | ∃\hat{} ∈ \{0,1\}^
\text{ such that } (\hat{}) =  \text{ and } \hat{} < \}.$$
The comparison $<$ is with respect to the integers of which $\hat{}, $ are the respective binary representations (in general, $$ is viewed as a map from integers to
integers).
Is the language $$ is in $\mathsf{NP}\setminus \mathsf{P}?$
My approach:

Guess a candidate $\hat{x}∈\{0,1\}^n$

Verify that $f(\hat{x})=y.$
Since  is computable in polynomial time, we can compute $f(\hat{x})$
and check if it equals  in polynomial time.

Verify that $\hat{x}<z$
.Comparing two -bit integers can be done in polynomial time as well.


Thus, a nondeterministic Turing machine can guess $\hat{x}$ and verify both conditions in polynomial time, which implies that $L \in \mathsf{NP}.$
If my $\mathsf{NP}$ logic is right, how can I show $L$ isn't in $\mathsf{P}$? Or any other way to show $$ is in $\mathsf{NP}\setminus \mathsf{P}?$

If you can prove that $L \in \textrm{NP} \setminus \textrm{P}$ then you have proven P $\ne$ NP and are entitled to a $1M USD prize.

@Mikero the initial assumption "there are $ \in {0,1}^$, for which, it cannot be computed efficiently)..." implies $P \ne NP$

Following the hints provided by @poncho, let us assume that $L \in \mathsf{P}$. This implies the existence of a polynomial time algorithm $A$ that, given an input $(y, z)$ can decide whether $(y, z) \in L$. We will show that there is a polynomial time algorithm $B$ (that uses $A$) that can invert $f$, i.e., given $y$, find a $\hat{x}$ such that $f(\hat{x}) = y$. This would imply that $f$ is easy to invert which is not the case, hence $L \notin \mathsf{P}$.
The algorithm $B$ essentially performs a binary search to find a preimage $\hat{x}$ such that $f(\hat{x}) = y$ using $A$ as follows. It first checks whether $f(2^n - 1) = y$ (i.e., whether the largest $n$-bit integer is a preimage). If the condition passes, $B$ output $2^n-1$. Otherwise, it checks if $A(y, 2^n - 1) = 1$. If this condition also fails, $B$ output $\bot$ (i.e., there does not exist a preimage). These initial checks are crucial because if the only preimage is $2^n−1$, it cannot be found solely using $A$, since $(y,z) \in L$ only guarantees the existence of an $x$ strictly smaller than $z$ as a preimage of $y$.
Now, if the second check passes, it means that there is a preimage in the range $[0, 2^n-1)$. $B$ will use binary search to find a preimage. $B$ first checks whether $f(2^{n-1}) = y$. If so, it outputs $2^{n-1}$. If not, it checks whether $A(y, 2^{n-1}) = 1$. If this check passes, then $B$ will do a binary search in the range $[0, 2^{n-1})$. Otherwise, it will do a binary search in the range $(2^{n-1}, 2^n-1)$.
It is easy to see that the algorithm $B$ terminates in $O(n)$ steps and the correctness is quite straight-forward.

Your demonstration that $L \in NP$ is correct

how can I show $L$ isn't in $P$?

Show the converse.  Assume that $L \in P$; that is, there is a polytime algorithm algorithm to compute $L$ on any input.
How could you use that to, given $ = ()$, find a $\hat{}∈ \{0,1\}^$ such that $(\hat{}) = $ in polynomial time?

How could you use that to, given $ = ()$, find a $\hat{}∈ {0,1}^$ such that $(\hat{}) = $ in polynomial time?--would you explain little bit? How to raise contradiction?

Actually I want show that given a $y∈im(f)$, we can compute a $\hat{x}$ such that $f(\hat{x})=y$
(in fact, the smallest one) in polynomial time.

@Xoxoxo: hint: use your $L$ oracle to find $\hat{x}$

To show that  $L \notin P$ , assume, for contradiction, that  $L \in P$ , meaning there is a polynomial-time algorithm to decide membership in $L$.
Given  $y = f(x)$, we can use this algorithm to find the smallest  $\hat{x}$ such that $f(\hat{x}) = y$  as follows:

For each integer  $z \in {0, 1}^n$ , query the $L$ -oracle with input $(y, z)$ .
The first $z$  for which the oracle returns "yes" is the smallest $\hat{x}$  such that  $f(\hat{x}) = y.$ continued..


Since $L \in P$  by assumption, this process runs in polynomial time. But this contradicts the assumption that finding $\hat{x}$  such that $f(\hat{x}) = y$ cannot be done in polynomial time. Therefore, $L \notin P$ , implying  $L \in NP \setminus P$ .

Would you check my argument is correct?

@Xoxoxo: checking $\hat{x}$ values sequentially takes more than polynomial time.  How can you do that faster?

That's my limitations of knowledge, that's why I request  you complete the answer by writing the sketch.

@Xoxoxo: well, this is an exercise, so I won't give you the answer.  However, if you need another hint, suppose you test $\hat{x} = 2^{n-1}$ first - what would an answer of true from $L$ tell you?  What would an answer of false tell you?
